# Soundcloud API Download

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am asking this here because Soundcloud does not have support. I going to build a website that people can purchase audio files from using Soundcloud to download the files (and stream before buy). I want to be able to access the download file link in the Soundcloud API without the download link being enabled and showing on the Soundcloud UI. I can't seem to find this info in the Soundcloud API docs. I am going to have a Paypal redirect after the payment to the download link. I know this is a weird way of doing this but I have certain criteria I have to meet. I would host the audio files on my server but they are huge. Anyone have experience with this or can help?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure its possible to do what you want. (very easily at least)

there would be no way for the purchaser to access the 'download' track on soundcloud directly unless downloads are specifically enabled for that track.

really the only way to not host the files and still be able to provide the download would be to use the api to download or proxy the track from soundcloud to your server, using your credentials (because you always have access to your own tracks, download or stream). mind you this would use 2x the bandwidth usage (the server getting the track from soundcloud, and the client downloading the track), and storage space would only be impacked on a temporary bases. but. this is a pretty hacky way and not really a good/proper solution.

you can:
-compress/re-encode the audio as to not use as much disk space
-pay for more storage space at your web host, its usually pretty cheap thse days.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to charge on something free? Well, I think all the downloader out there are middleware where they stream the track from soundcloud and response to client as attachment upon request, one of many examples is http://wittysound.com. Cheapest way to get thing done is providing direct link to soundcloud server like what http://soundflush.com does